# Is there a feature in Rider similar to smart break line in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, rider

I've recently moved from Visual Studio to Rider for Unity game development. Rider feels a lot better to use and provides a lot more features compared to Visual Studio, but I was too attached to the smart break line feature in Visual Studio.

I tried to look around but didn't find any promising solution or similar feature in Rider, so I figured out to ask for help here.

If you are wondering what smart break line does: here's a link:
[https://christiantricarico.net/blog/visual-studio-tip-smart-break-line-shift-enter/#:~:text=Smart%20Break%20Line%20is%20a,Break%20Line%20can%20help%20you](https://christiantricarico.net/blog/visual-studio-tip-smart-break-line-shift-enter/#:%7E:text=Smart%20Break%20Line%20is%20a,Break%20Line%20can%20help%20you).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options in Rider:

1. Pressing <kbd>{</kbd> always creates an opening and closing curly bracket `{<caret>}`. When hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> it will become properly formatted.
2. There are plenty of so-called [Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Using_Live_Templates.html). For example, when writing `class` and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>, Rider will let you choose the class name, create the braces and properly place the caret.

Comment: The first option is what I'm currently doing, but it takes more key presses compared to smart break line and I'm still getting used to it, so I would prefer if there is a way to achieve something like smart break line.

I researched about live templates before, and while they are very useful, there is no option to insert a template directly using shortkeys like Visual Studio Code snippets (if I'm not mistaken). So although they are useful for writing repeated code, it doesn't really solve my problem. Thanks for the suggestion anyways!